# Should I buy the Suica & N'EX package to go from Narita to Tokyo?

Tags: trains, public-transport, japan, tokyo

I read in [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5730/subway-train-or-both-when-travelling-around-tokyo) that maybe it's a good idea to buy this package to go from Narita to your hotel and have get some subway credit. [This page](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/suica-nex/) states that for ¥3500 I can get a one-way trip plus some credit.

First question: how much credit? In the upper part of the page it says it's ¥1500, but the "See how much you save!" figure says "Includes a ¥500 deposit".

Second question: I think it's not worth it for me, am I right? Using [Hyperdia](http://www.hyperdia.com/en/cgi/en/search.html?dep_node=NARITA%20AIRPORT%20TERMINAL%201&arv_node=KODEMMACHO&via_node01=&via_node02=&via_node03=&year=2012&month=10&day=28&hour=04&minute=39&search_type=0&search_way=&transtime=undefined&sort=0&max_route=5&ship=off&lmlimit=null&search_target=route&facility=reserved&sum_target=7) I found out that to go to my hotel in Chuo-Ku (Kodemmacho station) would cost only ¥1390. Am I doing something wrong? If this is right, I find it hard to believe it would be useful to someone.

Obs: for my trip back to the airport I will use the JR Pass, which will not be available when I get to Japan (bought the pass for 7 days in my 9 day trip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First question: how much credit? In the upper part of the page it says it's ¥1500, but the "See how much you save!" figure says "Includes a ¥500 deposit".

The deposit is the amount that is *not* credit - "deposit" means that you pay it and get it back when you return the card. So there's ¥1500 of credit.

> I think it's not worthy for me, am I right?

I'd say that a 110 yen fare difference should not be the reason to decide one way or another; at least for the first trip inside Japan and when carrying luggage, I'd choose the one that has the easiest connection.

> Using Hyperdia I found out that to go to my hotel in Chuo-Ku (Kodemmacho station) would cost only ¥1390. Am I doing something wrong?

No, it loooks right, and [Jorudan](http://www.jorudan.co.jp) agrees. It has even cheaper connections, but those take longer and/or include walking.

Comment: The other advantage of the Suica card is that it saves you a lot of fumbling around getting on and off the train, as you usually won't need to stop to do fare adjustments or fumble with which part of your wallet you left your ticket stub in, thanks to the proximity swipe feature of the Suica. Also, it will come in handy for the times that your JR pass doesn't help you, like when you take the subway or one of the non-JR lines. (Yu can also read your trip history/balance on some Android phones with NFC and an appropriate app). If you can get a package deal with extra credit, so much the better.

Comment: This package has been discontinued now, the replacement is http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/nex_round.html

Answer (score 4):

The Suica & NEX package has been [discontinued](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2359_suica_nex.html).

The replacement deal is the [NEX Tokyo Round Trip Ticket](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pass/nex_round.html).